# Decompress lrzip on Windows

Tags: linux, zip

I've happened upon *lrzip* as a compression tool, which compared to gzip, the compression was insane.

lrzip compressed a 300MB text file to 7MB where as gzip only managed to get it to 100MB.

I've transferred the file from an ubuntu machine to Windows but now not sure how I decompress lrzip files on Windows?

Comment: Were you able to decompress it even on linux? I can compress a file to 1 byte as well, if decompressability is not a real wish :-)

Comment: @PeterHorvath Yes of course I checked it ;) It's a mysql database backup using mysqldump - I sent it to a different linux machine and restored the database.

Comment: You might want to ask this on the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange after rephrasing it to something like "Windows program for decompressing lrzip archives".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways are possible:

1. Compile a Windows version yourself. The source of lrzip is [available on GitHub.](https://github.com/ckolivas/lrzip)
2. Use something that can be found on Google. I found an [old version](http://wesayso.co.uk/), that might not even work. And: always be careful when downloading precompiled binaries from the Internet. Some of them might contain unwanted effects (read: viruses, or something alike).
3. Use a different format. They might not be the optimal solution for your problem, but they will still achieve only slightly less compressed archives. Some might even be equally compressed. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is a free tool (one of the many. again: google for other options.) for Windows that supports many of the compression formats available on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

Cygwin comes with a Windows build of lrzip. You probably want the 64-bit version because according to lrzip manuals, it uses memory mapping for file access, which means 32-bit builds have severe limitations on file size.

1. Run the cygwin installer ([latest x64](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe))
2. Click Next a few times
3. Type "lrzip" in search, then expand Archive and click "Skip":

[image]

Optional step 4: go to your install's bin directory, find lrzip.exe and the *.dll files, move them to a location of your choice and delete Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Visit: https://code.google.com/archive/p/lrzip-decompressor/
This really helps.
How to use:
After downloading and installing, simply double-click any lrzip archive, and lrzip-decompressor will decompress it.